# mapView:viewForAnnotation: not called in iOS6, works fine in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, mapkit

I need to show a blue point (current user location) on my map. It's a trivial task, on my device with `iOS7` it works ok, on another device with `iOS6` it doesn't. I set map view's delegate from .xib, also my map is connected with controller through an outlet and I do not `init/alloc` this property in controller (I saw a lot of guys doing this). One more thing to notice is that `regionDidChangeAnimated` is called ok, and it's one of map view's delegate methods. I don't have idea why this happens.

Comment: http://openradar.appspot.com/12346693

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in IOS6, if you are added the **mapView:viewForAnnotation:**  after setting the delegate, then this delegate method will not be invoked. MapView will be use a default annotation view in this case. So try to remove your delegate connection from outlet and set the connection after a cleaning.

Comment: what do you mean by "set the connection after a cleaning" ? , set it back (outlet) after doing a clean of the project ?

Comment: nope, it doesn't help. I just tried to deploy on iOS 6.1.5 and it works, but on iOS 6.1.3 it doesn't